# Game losing goal

Tags: statistics, ice-hockey, own-goal

In the NHL, or generally in ice hockey and similar sports, there is a statistic of GWG - game winning goals. A goal is a GWG if it is enough for a team to score only until this goal with no more goals in the game and still win the match. For example, if team A wins a match 5:2, their third goal was the GWG. It does not need to be the last goal scored.

Now, I want to ask, what happens if the GWG is an own goal? I know that in the NHL, the concept of own goals does not exist. But maybe in other sports like field hockey or floorball, even football, or in other ice-hockey leagues etc, what would happen then? Is it meaningful to talk about a statistics of GLG - game losing goals? It would be an own goal which is enough for the opposing team to win a match with it.

Comment: The 2001 UEFA Cup final was decided a golden own-goal: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2000%E2%80%9301_UEFA_Cup#Final

Answer (score 2):

Own goals, as a statistic, are rare enough in football that they are not regularly tracked by all competitions, if at all (some do, like [the English Premier League](https://www.premierleague.com/stats/top/players/own_goals)).

They are [not even possible in field hockey](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/15883/), as the rules require an attacker to play the ball inside the circle for a goal to be scored.

Given their rarity on an absolute scale, and the number of matches in which they would matter to the result, tracking a game-losing own goal ("GLOG") statistic does not make much sense.

From a player analysis perspective, it doesn't make sense to worry about whether an own goal was the GLOG, since the player scoring enough OGs to have significant GLOGs is not a good enough player to be at the level where such tracking would occur.

Comment: I agree, but it would be definitely an interesting curious statistic for fans, if an GLG occurs :D